# Does Fritz "Blunder Check" mode respect "Side to Analyze" option?

Tags: software, fritz

I use Fritz 13, and in Blundercheck mode on a batch of games won by White, only want it to point out alternatives for the winner, that is white (I don't expect to have very many suggestions for improvement, because the games are selected as good wins by White). Yet I get a bunch of suggestions for improvement for Black, regardless of whether I pick "Side to analyze" as 'White' or 'Winner'. It seems that the output is the same whether I pick that, or 'Both'. Is this a bug in Fritz? Is anyone else seeing it work properly?